# is it recommended way to use media query while using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, responsive-design

I'm using bootstrap libraries for making responsive web application

For some  requirement i'm using media query for all the screen size as mentioned in below link

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

I've a doubt

1. whether its a right way to develop ?
2. Do i need to learn and use bootstrap more ,if yes how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not the right way. You need to learn about bootstrap fully. Its full for responsive designs. Its very easy to learn. Just refer this [website](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: thanks for your answer,i'm using that[http://getbootstrap.com/] only as for now and i'm struggling hard to use it when some complicated design ,could you please tell me the right approach to learn bootstrap and also i'm new to this field

Comment: Madhavan don't worry i m also new to bootstrap i learnt it 10 days only. Just open one asp.net solution in your pc, then open this website[getbootstrap.com/] , download the bootstrap files, paste it in your solution and give a css and js link in your webpage, then copy the code from website and paste it in your webpage and run it! Its simple!! If you have any doubt means, let me know i ll try to solve or just post your problem here. you will get the solution :)

Comment: jake the link http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c93bnmk32 is to be made responsive for all screen size how can we achieve using bootstrap now its not responsive

Comment: Use navbar for the header and also try to use collapse style in it. then use grid system for responsive in your body

Comment: the way u mentioned about asp.net solution could you explain me more because i cannot understand

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd831853(v=vs.110).aspx,   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0hds5k93(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: try this hope this may helpful

Comment: thanks @Jake i got it and here i am using zend eclipse for that purpose